# How do I make a TextBox empty once it's value is 0

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently making a Sudoku Solver in C# WPF. I made an multidimensional Array which is 9x9. Every element of this Array is a Property which is binded to a textbox in my WPF View.

So before I can assign it's elements to a property I have to initialize it because otherwise I would get a null reference exception. My code works fine, but after initializing my SudokuTable contains only Zeros. This is of course perfectly fine for calculations, but I would like the textboxes to contain nothing instead.

I'm fairly new to C# and WPF so I hope you can help me.
Below you will find my MainViewModel and one of the textboxes. Keep in mind that the binding works. It's just the 0 in the TextBox which I don't want.

MainViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public SudokuGrid SGrid { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SGrid = new SudokuGrid();
            InitializeSudokuTable();
        }

        private void InitializeSudokuTable()
        {
            SudokuTable = new int[9, 9];  
        }

        public int[,] SudokuTable
        {
            get { return SGrid.SudokuTable; }
            set
            {
                if (SGrid.SudokuTable != value)
                {
                    SGrid.SudokuTable = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Grid");
                }
            }
        }

        #region Cells
        public int Cell00
        {
            get { return SudokuTable[0, 0]; }
            set
            {
                if (SudokuTable[0, 0] != value)
                {
                    SudokuTable[0, 0] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

TextBox Example:

```
<TextBox MaxLength="1" Style="{StaticResource GridTextBox}" Text="{Binding Path=Cell00}"/>
```

Comment: you could change the type of `Cell00` to `string`. in the getter you convert the number to a string with .ToString(). in the setter you convert the string to a number with int.Parse(..). Problem: you have to validate that the user has input a numeric value and not some letters like "a"

Comment: As a hint, consider using an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel, and bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of 81 cell item objects. Then put the TextBox in the ItemTemplate. Then there might be a Binding Converter for the Text property, which converts `0` to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will try both of them.

Answer (score 0):

### nullable int

use a nullable `int?` as property type for `Cell00`:

```
private int _cell00 = 0;

public int? Cell00
{
    get
    {
        if (_cell00 == 0)
            return null;

        return _cell00;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            _cell00 = 0;

        _cell00 = (int) value;
    }
}
```

### string

using a string property and convert between string and int in the getter and setter works, too. but you would lose the automatic numeric validation of the textbox. Thus it will not warn you, when you type in a letter instead of a number.

```
private int _cell00 = 0;

public string Cell00
{
    get
    {

        if (_cell00 == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        return _cell00.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            _cell00 = 0;

        _cell00 = int.Parse(value);
    }
}
```